# Central CMS for MVC Websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I want to design a central CMS and control all website from this CMS. Admin area codes keep in CMS. And other site code keep in their website.

Example;

My website name is A. A has menus, and it has menus model like this;

```
public int MenusID{get;set;}

public string MenusName{get;set;}

public string MenusData{get;set;}
```

Other website name is B. B has menus too. It's model is like this;

```
public int MenusID{get;set;}

public string MenusName{get;set;}

public string MenusValue{get;set;}
```

When I add new menus from a. My view has to contain menusdata. When I add new menus from b . View have to contain menusvalue.

So, I want to all background admin side created by CMS.

My English is not good. Sorry for this. I hope you can understand me.

Comment: explain this line with example When i add new menus from a. My view have to contain menusdata. When i add new menus from b . View have to contain menusvalue.

Comment: sorry for late answer. I dont have internet.

this input creating with razor and ı create this with propertyinfo loop. But all of this have to running in CMS . so CMS look model and create the view but CMS and others different MVC project